# How to Create Model from this Dictionary?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to make form Input User from dictionary below but dont know to make it on django

```
    my_play = dict(
      name="may_first_play",
      hosts='cisco_firewalls',
      become='yes',
      become_method='enable',
      gather_facts='no',
      tasks=[
          dict(action=dict(module='asa_command', commands=['show version','show ip'])),
          dict(action=dict(module='asa_config', lines=['network-object host 10.1.0.1'])
      ]
  )
```

ihave make model like this but confusing on make on field tasks

```
    class Book(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     hosts = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     become = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     become_method = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     gather_facts = models.CharField(max_length=100)

     class task(Book):`
```

Please I will be very grateful if you help me

Comment: where is the tasks column in your model ?Or is it another model ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

And you need to add the tasks field in your model Book also.

```
class Book(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     hosts = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     become = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     become_method = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     gather_facts = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     tasks = models.TextField()

my_play = dict(
        name="may_first_play",
        hosts='cisco_firewalls',
        become='yes',
        become_method='enable',
        gather_facts='no',
        tasks=[
            dict(action=dict(module='asa_command', commands=['show version', 'show ip'])),
            dict(action=dict(module='asa_config', lines=['network-object host 10.1.0.1']))
        ]
    )

    book = Book(**my_play)
    book.save()
```